# Change viewmodel property from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Please can you help me with advice or demo code for the following task:

I had a program in WPF which constantly listen on a serial port, If it received a specific signal it should change a property in a ViewModel. The listener is start on another thread so I had wonder how can I change a ViewModel property from another thread, I try to pass a property by reference but that was not possible.

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    //My property in the view model
    private Boolean _Lock;
    public Boolean Lock
    {
        get { return _Lock; }
        set
        {
            _Lock = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Lock");
        }
    }

 //Start the listener thread
        Thread ComListenThread = new Thread(delegate() 
            {                  
                Com cm = new Com(Path,Lock);                    
                cm.Start();                    
            });
        ComListenThread.Start();


class Com
{

    private Uri web { get; set; }
    private Boolean Lock { get; set; }

    public Com(Uri Path,Boolean _Lock)
    {
        web = Path;                                
        Lock = _Lock;                                              
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            port = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Reason {0}:", e.Message);
        }

        port.ReadTimeout = 500;
        port.Open();

        int position = 0;            
        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                int len = port.Read(data, position, data.Length - position);
                position += len;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {


                //How to change Lock property 
                Lock = (data[2]==5)?true:false;


                position = 0;
            }
        }
    }                      
}
```

So my question is how can I pass the property which will be changed on another thread in constant loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By passing the *parent object* you should have access to the property to change it; however, you may want to switch back to the UI thread (Dispatcher.Invoke) before doing this, as cross-threaded mutation of "observer" models rarely ends well.

Another approach is for your code to simply raise an event (nothing to do with this property), and have your UI code switch to the UI tread and update the view-model. This approach separates the UI code cleanly from the "doing" code (since the "doing" code knows nothing of the view-model or threading), and is particularly useful if you need to support arbitrary UI models.